# Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.1

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6.3

Is there any way to have Xcode 6.3 compile Swift using version 1.1?  I upgraded to Xcode 6.3 today, expecting great bugfixes and being able to convert 1.1 code to 1.2.  Unfortunately, rainbows and unicorns are nowhere to be found.

Now I have a broken project and I want to just revert back to compiling using Swift 1.1.

Eclipse would allow you to compile against another version of Java. Is this possible in Xcode and Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There's no way to compile against an older version using a newer version of Xcode of pretty much anything except for older iOS versions in this ecosystem. That said, I believe this is on purpose. It's a good idea to keep up to date with the latest versions of everything.

One possible solution however is to go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action and download Xcode 6.2 and remove Xcode 6.3. This should install the tools for Swift 1.1 and remove the tools for 1.2. But again, it's a good idea to just revise your code to reflect the changes in Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can install XCode 6.2 to a different folder and use both Versions. You just have to be carefull to start the right version everytime.
In the preferences you can also set the Version of the Tools you want to use. You could use the Dev Tools from 6.3 with XCode 6.2 for example.

Reverting the CODE is possible if you have used git or svn.

Comment: You can even install it to the same folder, just rename Xcode.app to something like Xcode-6.2.app.